# how to give style to single character

Tags: css, dom, superscript

How to apply style to single character where ever it is occurring in the web page. For example 'Welcome' in this word i have to give superscript to only 'e'. How to apply different font for single character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841205/how-to-apply-a-style-to-a-single-special-html-character-across-the-page

Comment: Tried my level best but not able to find. This is the actual issue Recently we have changed myriad to "Open sans" after that Registered symbol (®)  is not showing as super scripted. How to handle this.

Comment: The you might try `unicode-range` and use a different font for that **character only**

Comment: @Paulie_D: I have tried using servlet filter to replace the string when the response is rending. It got worked but not sure it will affect the performance or not. I am finding now what is the best way to fix the superscript issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245888/css-font-unicode-range

Comment: @Paulie_D using unicode-range with different font resolved the issue. Thanks for your great input.

Answer (score 0):

```css
span{
 vertical-align: super;
 font-size:18px;
 }
 
 sup{font-size:18px;}
```

```html
<p>'W<span>e</span>lcom<span>e</span>'</p>

<p>W<sup>e</sup>lcom<sup>e</sup> </p>
```

Comment: The problem is how to wrap the data in the best way <sup>@</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly resolved the problem.

```
 @font-face{
    font-family:Myriad ;
    src:url(Myriad-normal.ttf);
    unicode-range:U+00AE;
 }
```

Please see this link to get more information on this topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range