# How to change size of registration trademark with CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello I have simple h2 and I want to change size of this registration trademar. Can somebody help me with this?

```css
h2 {
color: #fff}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem®</h2>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245888/css-font-unicode-range

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I've put `color: #fff` into a comment so that the text is not white – this makes it easier to see the example!

To put styles on a specific piece of text, I would always put a `span` tag around it. Here, I've given this tag a `class` of 'trademark'.

In the CSS, you can then change the size of the trademark using `font-size`. In my example, I've made the trademark much smaller, but you can do anything you want to it!

```css
h2 {
  /*color: #fff*/
}

.trademark {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Lorem<span class="trademark">®</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Note I have replaced the trademark symbol with the [name code](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp) and commented the colour so you can see, but just change these as desired.

First, you may want to consider the superscript as standard for this type of thing.

```css
h2 {
/* color: #fff */}

/* To customise size of text in a superscript use:
sup { 
font-size: whatever you like but the default looks nice }*/
```

```html
<h2>Lorem<sup>&reg</sup></h2>
```

Alternatively, you can wrap it in a span and customise that. I have chosen a font-size of 15px but change it as desired!

```css
h2 {
/* color: #fff */}

span{ 
font-size: 15px;}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem<span>&reg</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .html file

```
<h2>
    Lorem<span id="trademark">&reg</span>
</h2>
```

and in the .css file add this (40px is an optional)

```
#trademark{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```